# In Arch, web browsers crash when opening file finder dialogue window

Tags: arch-linux, browser, troubleshooting, glib

I recently update my Arch, and I am currently running kernel version 5.6.6-arch1-1. When I try to open a file finder window either from Firefox or from Chrome (e.g. uploading an email attachment), both browsers crash. The error given in Firefox is:

```
(firefox:3606): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 19:32:17.971: Settings schema 'org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser' does not contain a key named 'show-type-column'
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 3841
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Now, following along with some posts I found online, I discovered that `GLib` searchers for these gtk schemas based on what is in the `XDG_DATA_DIRS` environment variable. However, I found that in my case that variable was empty. In my `~/.xinitrc` (not sure if I should do this elsewhere) I added a line

```
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/:/usr/local/share
```

And rebooted. However, the error persists and now I am not sure what to do. I ran `find -iname org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser /` and the only result is in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` as it should be. Furthermore, that xml file has a field name `show-type-column` so if the system is finding it (which I am not sure of), then everything should be alright.

Does anyone have pointers as to what to do? This is extremely inconvenient so I am all ears

Answer (score 2):

After tinkering around the last day or two, I managed to fix things. In the end I think the fact that `XDG_DATA_DIRS` was not set was a red herring, as the final fix didn't involve setting that variable. Also, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820733/firefox-hangs-because-sort-directories-first-setting-missing) answer was quite useful.

The fix involved first recompiling the glib2 schemas using:

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

and then reinstalling Firefox

```
sudo pacman -S firefox
```

Just recompiling the schemas did not work, nor did reinstalling Firefox as I had tried to do so the other day. Somehow, the combination of the two was needed. Still not sure what was broken, but this is how I fixed it.